# Динамически создать таблицу и заполнить данными из массива

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов с пользователями(users). Нужно создать таблицу с 11 строками и 2мя ячейками в каждой строке. В первой строке должна быть шапка(первая ячейка - username, вторая - score). И нужно эту таблицу заполнить значениями из массива уже отфильтрованного(чтобы сначала был юзер с самым большим значением score и тд). Как заполнить таблицу данными из массива? В данный момент получилось только сделать шапку таблицы.

```
let filteredScore = [];
let users = [
    {userName: "12345@ff.fg", password: "wedrftg", score: -6},
    {userName: "qwasder@ss.ff", password: "wddesdsdftg", score: 1},
    {userName: "q4567r@ss.ff", password: "23467", score: 2}
    ];
if(users.length) {
    filteredScore = users.sort((a,b) => {
       return b.score - a.score;
    });

}
const table = document.createElement('table');
for(let i=0; i<11; i++) {

    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.appendChild( document.createElement('td'));
    tr.appendChild( document.createElement('td'));

    table.appendChild(tr);
    table.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = 'Username';
    table.rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML = 'Score';

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let users = [{
    userName: "12345@ff.fg",
    password: "wedrftg",
    score: -6
  },
  {
    userName: "qwasder@ss.ff",
    password: "wddesdsdftg",
    score: 1
  },
  {
    userName: "q4567r@ss.ff",
    password: "23467",
    score: 2
  }
];

users.sort((a, b) => {
  return b.score - a.score;
});


const fill = (arr) => {
  let table = document.createElement('table');
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(tr);
  tr.appendChild(document.createElement('th'));
  tr.appendChild(document.createElement('th'));
  table.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = 'Username';
  table.rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML = 'Score';

  document.body.appendChild(table);
  let i = 1;

  arr.forEach(elem => {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(tr);
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    table.rows[i].cells[0].textContent = elem.userName;
    table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = elem.score;
    i++;
  });
};

fill(users)
```